# Integrate SSO using External database in JasperReports Server

Tags: single-sign-on, jasperserver

I am trying to integrate SSO using External database. For this I have created external DB on *PostgreSQL* in which I have created a table(user table) with following fields

```
user table
1.userid-bigint
2.Username -charcter varying(100)
3.password--charcter varying(100)
4.Fullname--charcter varying(100)
5.tenantid etc.
```

Now i want to login *JasperReports Server* using external database. It means if i login *JR Server* using external database then it should be login successfully and redirect to home page of *JR server*. Can you please suggest what should i do for this?